# Measure on $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ having uniformly bounded central moments

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, moment-problem

Consider $\Bbb R$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$. Let $\mathcal \mu:\mathcal B(\Bbb R)\to[0,\infty]$ be a measure such that for all $p\in [1,\infty)$ there exists $M>0\ ($indepedent of $p)$ with $$\int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x)<M.$$ Now, one such measure is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta_{c_n}}{n^2}$$ where each $c_n\in [-1,1]$. I want to find out all such $\mu$ having uniformly bounded central moments. Is it possible?

Note that by Chebyshev's inequality if $\mu$ is such a measure then $\mu\big((-\infty,\epsilon]\cup [\epsilon,\infty)\big)\leq \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: It's easy to see this holds if and only if $\mu((-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty))=0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich , For a necessary and suficient condition, I think we also need some condition on how $\mu$ behaves in $[-1,1]$.. In the question, it is not stated that $\mu$ is a Borel measure. It is just a mesure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ramiro Interesting. I just checked on wikipedia, and indeed it states there that some authors make the additional assumption that $\mu(C) < +\infty$ for compact $C$. I have never before seen that used, so far every definition of Borel measure I've come across was "measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra".

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, there are more than one definition of "Borel measure".  The definition of Borel measure requiring it to be finite on compact sets can be found, for instance, in Halmos "Measure Theory" ($\S$ 52).

Comment: @Sumanta You wrote that you want to find out all such $\mu$ having uniformly bounded central moments and you ask if it is possible.  
Yes, it is possible. I have posted an answer demonstrating a **necessary and sufficient condition** for $\mu$ to have  uniformly bounded central moments.

Please, let me know if you have question regarding my answer.

Comment: @Sumanta Thanks for accepting my answer. I hope you have followed the short conversation between David Ullrich, Daniel Fischer and me. There are (at least) two definitions of Borel measure. One (from Halmos, for instance) requires the measure to be defined on Borel $\sigma$-algebra and to be finite on compact sets (no condition on regularity).  When I saw David's comment, I thought he was reading your question as regarding Borel measures (in Halmos' sense). That is why I highlighted, in my comment to David, that your question does not use the term "Borel measure", so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Ramiro Yeah, you are right. I am assuming just a measure (not a Radon measure) i.e. non-negativity, the measure of the empty set is zero, and countable additivity. If I assume regularity assumption then I don't add the last note using Chebyshev's inequality because letting $\epsilon\to 0+$ we have no control over near to $0$, so we don't know $\mu(\Bbb R-\{0\})$, whether it is finite or not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that if I assume that for each $p\in [1,\infty)$ and for each $x_0\in \Bbb R$ we have a $M>0$, independent of both $x_0$ and $p$ such that $\int_\Bbb R |x-x_0|^p\ d\mu(x)<M$ then $\mu=0$. That is to say, measure on Borel sigma-algebra having uniformly bounded all moments(central or not) is nothing but zero measure.

Comment: @Sumanta: Not quite surprising since then you’d be requiring that $\mu[|x-x_0|>1)=0$ for all $x_0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for your comment. Is my idea in "Another interesting thing is that if I assume that for each....." correct?

Comment: @Sumanta In fact, if a  measure has uniform bounded all moments with respect to two points $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $|x_0 -x_1|>2$ then the measure has to be identically $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you want to find out all such $\mu$ having uniformly bounded central moments and you ask if it is possible.

Yes, it is possible. The result below establishes a **necessary and sufficient condition** for $\mu$ to have  uniformly bounded central moments.

> Let $\mathcal \mu:\mathcal B(\Bbb R)\to[0,\infty]$ be a measure. Then, there exists $M>0$ such that, for all $p\in [1,\infty)$,  $$\int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x)<M$$ if and only $\mu(\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1])=0$ and $\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$.

**Proof**:

$1$.  Suppose $\mu(\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1])=0$ and  $\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$. Then
for all $p\in [1,\infty)$,
$$\int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x) = \int_{[-1,1]} \big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x) \leqslant \int_{[-1,1]} |x| d\mu(x)$$
And since $\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$, just take $M= 1+\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$.

2. Suppose that there exists $M>0$ such that, for all $p\in [1,\infty)$,  $$\int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x)<M$$

Then for any $n\in \Bbb N -\{0\}$, we have, for all $p\in [1,\infty)$ and for all $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $|x|\geqslant 1+\frac{1}{n}$, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^p \leqslant \big|x\big|^p$. So we have,
$$(1+{1}/{n})^p\mu(\{|x|\geqslant 1+{1}/{n}\})\leqslant\int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|^p\ d\mu(x)<M.$$

Since this is true for  all $p\in [1,\infty)$, we have, for any $n\in \Bbb N -\{0\}$, that
$$\mu(\{|x|\geqslant 1+{1}/{n}\})=0$$
Thus we have that $$\mu(\{|x|> 1\})=0$$

We have proved that $\mu(\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1])=0$.

Now, just considering $p=1$, we have
$$\int_{[-1,1]} |x| d\mu(x) = \int_\Bbb R\big|x\big|\ d\mu(x)<M$$
So we proved that  $\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$.

**Additional comment**: if you assume additionally that $\mu$ is finite on compact sets, then we "automatically" have that $\mu([-1,1])<\infty$ and so $\int_{[-1,1]}|x|d\mu(x) < \infty$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz , My answer does not mention the term "Borel measure". In my answer, all that is assumed is just that $\mu$ is a measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M=\sup_{p\geq1}\int|x|^p\,\mu(dx)<\infty$.

By Markov-Chebyshev's, for any $a>1$ and any $p\geq1$

$$\mu(|x|>a)\leq\frac{1}{a^p}\int |x|^p\mu(dx)\leq\frac{M}{a^p}\xrightarrow{p\rightarrow\infty}0$$

This means that $\mu(|x|>a)=0$ for all $a>1$; hence $\mu(|x|>1)=0$.

---

Conversely, if $\mu(|x|>1)=0$, then $m_p:=\int|x|^p\,d\mu(x)=\int_{[-1,1]}|x|^p\,\mu(dx)$

If $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure (a.k.a [Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure)), $\mu([-1,1])<\infty$ and so,  $\sup_{p\geq1}m_p\leq \mu([-1,1])<\infty$. If $\mu$ is not regular (for example $\mu(dx)=\frac{dx}{|\log x|}$), then $\{m_p\}$ may failed to be bounded. For such measures,  a sufficient condition for uniform boundedness of $\{m_p\}$ is  $\int|x|\,\mu(dx)<\infty$, In which case,  $\sup_pm_p=m_1$.